C disassembly - bitwise operations with 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and 0x8000000000000000
I am using IDA to reverse engineer x86_64 binary file written in C. And pretty often I meet the following in IDA's pseudocode:

(int64)v7 | 0x8000000000000000LL
(int64)v7 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL

While researching I figured out that:

0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is 9223372036854775807, which is signed long MAX value in C
0x8000000000000000 is -9223372036854775808, which is signed long MIN value in C

But I can't wrap my head around how to translate these bitwise operations with MIN and MAX into "normal" C coding pattern.
Can anybody please explain ?

the two functions set and clear the sign bit ... there is no reason to translate the two values to decimal

what do you mean by "normal" C coding pattern?

Could you please explain how these functions set and clear sign bit ?

research C bitwise operators

When you see such masks - remember these key rules for bitwise arithmetic
Assume X is unknown, & is bitwise AND, | is bitwise OR

X & 1 = X
X & 0 = 0
X | 0 = X
X | 1 = 1

Now look at the mask and its operation. In this case
v7 | 0x8000000000000000LL
The mask
In [1]: 0x8000000000000000 == 1 << 63
Out[1]: True

So in this case a 64 bit number - with the most significant bit (MSB) set and all other 0s
index - 63 62 61 ... 2 1 0
bits  - 1  0  0  ... 0 0 0

The operation here is | - the bitwise OR
We don't know v7 - we can assume it to be X. For individual bits X_i for i index
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0

When bitwise OR is done -
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0
mask  - 1    0    0    ... 0   0   0

With the rules mentioned above - we can operate X | 1 = 1
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0
mask  - 1    0    0    ... 0   0   0
result- 1 

for the rest unknown bits X | 0 = X
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0
mask  - 1    0    0    ... 0   0   0
result- 1    X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0 

We can see that all of the bits of result is the same as v7 except the MSB which is now 1.
Therefore, v7 | 0x8000000000000000LL sets the MSB of v7
Similarly for v7 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
The mask is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL, which has all bits set to 1 except for the most significant bit (MSB), which is 0.
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bits  - 0    1    1    ... 1   1   1

We want to perform the bitwise AND operation between v7 and the mask.
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0

When we perform the bitwise AND operation:
For each bit position, we apply the rule X & 1 = X and X & 0 = 0
index - 63   62   61   ... 2   1   0
bitsX - X_63 X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0
mask  - 0    1    1    ... 1   1   1
result- 0    X_62 X_61 ... X_2 X_1 X_0

The result retains all bits of v7 except the MSB, which is now 0. Therefore, v7 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL clears the MSB of v7
In signed values the MSB dictates the sign of the number - a set MSB means -ve and unset means a +ve number.
Now if v7 is a signed value - we can see the change in values with this python snippet
In [9]: x = 0xabcdef1234567890

In [10]: ctypes.c_uint64(x & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
Out[10]: c_ulong(3156441775323117712)

In [11]: (ctypes.c_int64(x & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).value)
Out[11]: 3156441775323117712

In [12]: ctypes.c_int64(x).value
Out[12]: -6066930261531658096

With the MSB cleared the signed and unsigned values of the result is same.
In [13]: (ctypes.c_int64(x | 0x8000000000000000).value)
Out[13]: -6066930261531658096

In [14]: (ctypes.c_uint64(x | 0x8000000000000000).value)
Out[14]: 12379813812177893520

In [15]: x
Out[15]: 12379813812177893520

With the MSB set - the number stays as is if it was a signed negative earlier.
